# SQL Server MERGE ON statement failing to detect matches

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have a table `address` that has a unique constraint across all of its columns `line_1, line_2, site_town, site_county, postal_code, country` (except id - which is the primary key and auto-incremented). All of these columns are also nullable. Any identical rows (including matching null values) should be caught during the merge.

My query:

```
MERGE INTO address WITH (HOLDLOCK) as TARGET
USING (SELECT
          Address_Line_1,
          Address_Line_2,
          Address_Town,
          Address_County,
          Address_Postcode,
          Address_Country
      FROM RAW_CM_Companies
    ) AS SOURCE ON (Target.line_1 = Source.Address_Line_1 OR 
                    (Target.line_1 IS NULL AND Source.Address_Line_1 IS NULL))
                   AND (Target.line_2 = Source.Address_Line_2 OR 
                        (Target.line_2 IS NULL AND Source.Address_Line_2 IS NULL))
                   AND (Target.site_town = Source.Address_Town OR 
                        (Target.site_town IS NULL AND Source.Address_Town IS NULL))
                   AND (Target.site_county = Source.Address_County OR 
                        (Target.site_county IS NULL AND Source.Address_County IS NULL))
                   AND (Target.postal_code = Source.Address_Postcode 
                        OR (Target.postal_code IS NULL AND Source.Address_Postcode IS NULL))
                   AND (Target.country = Source.Address_Country 
                        OR (Target.country IS NULL AND Source.Address_Country IS NULL))

    -- when matched don't do anything

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (line_1, line_2, site_town, site_county, postal_code, country)
      VALUES (Source.Address_Line_1, Source.Address_Line_2, Source.Address_Town, Source.Address_County, Source.Address_Postcode, Source.Address_Country);
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__address__0562CB2F819EDD16'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.address'. The duplicate key value is (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, United Kingdom).

How is my ON statement not detecting this?

Comment: The `NULL`s were hidden because you used HTML (`<NULL>`). Also, please read all the links in [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge) and specifically read [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) for a better UPSERT pattern.

Comment: Or since you're not updating, you could just set IGNORE DUP KEY on the index and use INSERT.  And if the key violation is because of a concurrent MEGE, you'll  UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK.  Otherwise the scan phase of MERGE only uses S locks.

Comment: You might still have duplicates in RAW_CM_Companies. Also, feel free to stop using merge